# KSH password generator

Tags: linux, random, passwords, generator, ksh

how to make sure that the generated passwords contains all these special characters (?!/=) ?

Currently I'm using:

```
pwd_usr["$i"]=`cat /dev/urandom|tr -dc "a-zA-Z0-9-_\?\!\=\/\"|fold -w 15|head -n 1`
```

But some of the generated passwords might not contain the special characters I want. Please help. Thanks.

Comment: still i am waiting you to tell me for which reason you want this to be done automatically......because i think you are just looking for ready made stuff......

Comment: you can also generate a password of 11 positions, add the 4 mandatory characters and make a random shuffle function.

Answer (score 0):

i would suggest do this manually so you can check it out yourself, so:

```
i=0
while i -lt 100
do
    i=$(expr i + 1)
    var=$(pwd_usr["$i"]=`cat /dev/urandom|tr -dc "a-zA-Z0-9-_\?\!\=\/\"|fold -w 15|head -n 1`)
done
echo $var
```

So like this, you will create 100 passwords, store them in `var` and then from the output of echo you can check if actually the passwords contain what you want, and then be happy or keep on working :)

**P.S**

To make this easier for yourself, after all output gets printed just copy all of it to an editor and use `search`, `control+F`, you know, and add the characters you want in order to save lots of time.